# Where to get the Redirect URI and/or ClientId of an existing Asp.Net Core App

Tags: azure, authentication, asp.net-core, active-directory

I have an existing asp.net core 2.0 web app that uses a local database to store logins (individual user accounts). However, I now want to hide a page on the applications behind AD authentication.

I created another test app selecting 'work or school accounts' to see what that looks like, using the correct domain. That new app lets me log in with my work AD account right off the bat, and so I took all of the relevant code from that new test app and put it in my old application so that it routes to that microsoft sign in page when you click the correct page link. Everything seems to be working and hooked up correctly, except after logging in I get this message:

AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application: '[the ClientId I put in appsettings]'

I copied over the appsettings section as well from the test project for the AzureAd configuration, but of course I need the ClientId for my already existing project, not from the test project. The relevant appsettings section looks like this:

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "XXXX.com",
    "TenantId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", //this seems to be the same everywhere and is fine?
    "ClientId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", //this is app specific and generated automatically when the app is created?
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
```

My question is, where can I find that ClientId for my existing application? Every answer to this I look says you have to get it or set it up in Azure, but we don't actually use Azure, instead that ClientId is generated automatically by Visual Studio when I create the application (it still works for logging in on the test app so I guess I don't need azure for this?). Where do I get the ClientId for an existing app? Or, how can I add it to an existing app? Or generate one that will be accepted?

Thanks

**EDIT** (added from comment below):
thanks for your response. I have logged into azure portal. The test application I made was in there, but not the new application that was first made with local accounts. So, I added the new application, took it's generated applicationid and put it in the appsettings as the client id. I also generated a key for the application inside azure portal, but I am unsure what to do with that key. It appears now though that I am able to successfully authenticate, in that after logging it it gives me the "would you like to stay logged in..." option, but then on redirect it just does Working...indefinitely.so I think the issue now is with redirect.

The reply url I have in azure portal is just

https://localhost:44320/signin-oidc

I just put that in there to imitate the working test application which has the same thing but a different number, (this number matches the local host number that the new app uses in developement in launch settings). In the c# in AccountController I have tried a lot of things including the default

`var redirectUrl = Url.Action(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");`

but the redirect always gets stuck on Working...

Also, strangely, now every link on the site redirects to the azure login, rather than only the one link I initially setup to redirect to the login action on the accountcontroller for azure, which is odd and not the behavior I need. How do I fix that?

thanks

Comment: The reply url it's complaining about is the one registered in the azure portal. You need to update that to point to your other app.

Comment: *instead that ClientId is generated automatically by Visual Studio when I create the application* -> VS creates an app registration on Azure for you. So you can still look it up in the portal.

Comment: You obviously have some Azure AD tenant since the login worked :) Login to portal.azure.com with your work AD account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers here are correct. If you were able to successfully publish the app from Visual Studio, a Client ID would have already been generated. Use your Visual Studio account to log into the Azure portal. Then find the app by either searching the name from the resources list or checking under the App Services blade. When you click into the app, you will want to copy the Application ID and paste it into the Client ID section in the web.config. (Client ID and Application ID are synonymous even though they are named differently.)

With regard to the reply URL question, you just need to make sure that the Redirect URI and the reply URLs are matching. Normally you would just put the application homepage URL in both sections, unless you wanted to direct the users somewhere else. (So it would just be https://myapp.azurewebsites.net)

Comment: thanks for your response. I have logged into azure portal. The test application I made was in there, but not the new application that was first made with local accounts. So, I added the new application, took it's generated applicationid and put it in the appsettings as the client id. I also generated a key for the application inside azure portal, but I am unsure what to do with that key. It appears now though that I am able to successfully log in, in that after logging it it gives me the "would you like to stay logged in..." option, but then on redirect it just does Working...indefinitely.

Comment: Do you mean that it redirects indefinitely? You need to make sure that the URL in the reply URL section and in the webconfig (RedirectURI section) are matching. I don't think you need to add the key unless you are using a Client Secret (in which case you would copy the key and paste it into the Client Secret value in the web.config). Have you checked out this documentation? https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect

(Just ignore the part in the document that says to use localhost.)

Comment: thanks Marilee, I figured out the routing issue, I was ultimately routing back to sign in after signing in, hence the loop. Everything is working now as far as I can tell. Thanks again!